# Get date-time of directory and compare

Tags: python, time, compare, directory, seconds

```
import os

print(str(os.stat('/home/zarkopafilis/Python/test2.py').st_mtime))
```

Returns large values like :
1378906011.07

Within 5 seconds I run  :

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(str(now.second))
```

It returns :
1-5(Depending how fast it runs)

How can I check the time that the file was created and see if X seconds have passed by the time script runs?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
>>> time_diff = time.time() - os.stat('/home/zarkopafilis/Python/test2.py').st_mtime                                                                   
>>> hours, rest = divmod(time_diff, 3600)                                                                                                    
>>> minutes, seconds = divmod(rest, 60)                                                                                                      
>>> print hours                                                                                                                              
0.0
>>> print minutes
1.0
>>> print seconds
51.3503739834
```

Now that you have stored the time difference in the variables `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds` you can check if `seconds >= X` where X is the number of seconds you are interested in waiting for.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`1378906011.07` is the number that represent seconds from epoch (January 1st 1970).

You can see the time using [`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1378906011.07)
datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 11, 22, 26, 51, 70000)
>>> print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1378906011.07))
2013-09-11 22:26:51.070000
```

Use `time.time()` to get current date-time as the second:

```
>>> time.time()
1378906919.446

>>> t1 = time.time()
>>> t2 = time.time() # a few second later
>>> t2 - t1
18.51900005340576
```

`time.time() - os.stat('/home/zarkopafilis/Python/test2.py').st_mtime` will give you passed time.